# How to test vm.variable - function(){..} unit testing with jasmine?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-scope, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am using karma- jasmine framework to test my angular application. I'm facing a problem in calling the functions of the controller or service form my test-spec. I tried using controller. as well as scope. but both of them didn't work for me.

The controller code is

```
(function () {'use strict';

angular.module('selfUi').controller('AttendeesController', AttendeesController);

AttendeesController.$inject = ['$state', '$stateParams', 'AttendeeService', 'settings', '$log'];

function AttendeesController($state, $stateParams, AttendeeService, settings, $log) {
  var vm = this;
  if ($stateParams.attendeeData === null) {
  vm.pageType = "Add Attendee";
  vm.isEdit = false;
  } else {
  var tempAttendee = $stateParams.attendeeData;
  vm.pageType = "Edit Attendee";
  vm.isEdit = true;
  vm._id = tempAttendee._id;
  vm.firstName = tempAttendee.firstName;
  vm.lastName = tempAttendee.lastName;
 }
  vm.checkAvailable = function(email){
        //Check email
        if(email === null || angular.isUndefined(email) || email.trim().length === 0){
            vm.invalidEmail = true;
        }else{
            // Check if email is already present or not 
            success = function(data, status, headers, config) {
                if(data[0].success){
                    vm.validEmail = true;
                }else{
                    if(data[0].message){
                        modalData = {
                            success : false,

                        };
                    }else{
                        vm.validEmail = false;

                    }
                }
            };
            failure = function(data, status, headers, config) {
                 vm.invalidEmail = false;
            };

            AttendeeService.checkEmail(email, success, failure);
        }
    };
      } })();
```

My test spec is:

```
describe('AttendeesController', function(){
beforeEach(module('SS'));

var state, $stateParams, stateParams, settings, AttendeeService, log;
var email= "temp@email.com";
var controller, $scope;
var vm;

$stateParams= {_id : "1",
  attendeeType : "attendee",
  firstName : "Pen",
  lastName : "Red",
  email : "temp@email.com",
  company : "SWG",
  jobTitle : "Speaker",
  biography : "bio",
  tagsInterest : "interests"}


  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, _AddAttendeeService_, $controller, $state,   $stateParams,settings, $log) {
AttendeeService= _AttendeeService_;
state= $state;
$scope = $rootScope.$new();
controller = function() {
  return $controller('AttendeesController', {
    $scope : scope,
    $stateParams : $stateParams
  });
};

}));




it('should be instantiated', function() {
  expect(AttendeeService).toBeDefined();
});

it('should have controller.methods defined', function(){
  expect(controller).toBeDefined();
  expect(controller.checkAvailable).toBeUndefined();
  controller.checkAvailable(email);

});
```

});

My service code looks like this:

```
 (function() {
 'use strict';
 angular.module('SS').service('AttendeeService', AttendeeService);

AttendeeService.$inject = ['SSFactory', 'settings', '$rootScope'];

function AttendeeService(SelfSFactory, settings, $rootScope){

    this.addAttendee = function(data, success, failure){

        var responsePromise = SelfServiceFactory.httpPostRequest(settings.createAttendeeURL, data, config);
        responsePromise.success(success);
        responsePromise.error(failure);
        return responsePromise;
    };
 }});
```

When I run my test spec, it gives me a error

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'controller.checkAvailable(email)')
    at C:/Users/IBM_ADMIN/WebstormProjects/Self/self-service-ui.git/src/tests/addAttendees.controller.spec.js:53
```

I tried calling the checkAvailable function with the scope variable too, but it didn't work. I need to know how to call such methods in the controller from my test spec.

Comment: Why did you wrap `$controller()` in a function? In your test file : `controller = function() {
  return $controller(...) };`. Try to just assign it: `controller = $controller(...)` or if you actually need a function for it, then you have to call `controller()` to get the return value: `expect(controller().checkAvailable).toBeDefined();`

Comment: I tried without wrapping in a function too, but it was throwing this error:
    TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'tempAttendee._id')
 undefined
And I tried  expect(controller().checkAvailable).toBeDefined():
It was throwing the same error as above, undefined is not an object...

Comment: That's because you set your `$stateParams` in tests wrong. In controller you have `var tempAttendee = $stateParams.attendeeData;`, but in tests you don't have this property `attendeeData`. Therefore you get `undefined` in `tempAttendee` variable and eventually you get an error when trying to access the `_id` property of undefined `tempAttendee` .

Comment: Okay. I fixed that error. Thanks. :) But how do i call checkAvailable(email)? I tried calling by using controller().checkAvailable(email); But it says undefined to be defined. I'm new to this testing framework, so I don't have much clue.

Comment: Your `checkAvailable()` method does not return anything explicitly, that's why you get `undefined`.

Comment: Okay. Thanks.
What would you recommend to do in-order to test that method in controller.

Comment: You have to decide what behavior do you want to test and depending on that - write a test)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help :)